# How can I list archived projects in a group?

Tags: gitlab

I am navigating in a GitLab project group that contains a number of archived projects. How can I list all the archived projects in this group?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to see  the settings within the main `Groups`->`Group Project` page, and change the setting as seen in the screenshot below.

[image: Show Archived Projects]

Comment: Wow. That's some incredibly bad UX. Why hide it inside the sort order dropdown? :S